# programming slack to create channel for website

Tags: slack, channel

how do I can create a slack channel for a specific website? for example, I want to have the AWS blog content (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/) in a slack channel.

Comment: Your question might fit better on the [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange, since it appears to be about configuring Slack, not programming in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want to have new blog posts from AWS automatically sent to a Slack channel you can use the RSS Slack integration (https://slack.com/apps/A0F81R7U7-rss) with https://aws.amazon.com/new/feed/ and select any existing channel or create a new channel specifically for it.